# How to reload nested state of different controller when changing selectbox content in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-change

How to reload nested state of different controller when changing selectbox content in AngularJS?

I have 2 select boxes 
1.Category and 
2.SubCategory

Based on the category and subcategory, Products will be displayed on the inner state

category and subcategory come under addproducts state

products come under .productsettings state inside the addproducts state

But my problem is when I select both category and subcategory the product will be displayed
that means

```
$state.go('addproducts.productsettings');
```

will work,But after selecting both after that when i change only subcategory selectbox  it won't reload product state

```
$state.go('addproducts.productsettings');
```

will not work that wont load in ProductSettingsController

This is my html code it contains two select boxes

```
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Category</b></label>
        <select ng-model="selectedCategory" class="form-control" id="categories" ng-init="selectedCategory = null" 
        ng-change="onCategoryChange(selectedCategory)"> 
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in categories | orderBy:'catName'| groupBy:'catName'">{{key}}</option>           
                </select>           
      </div>              
    </form>     
    <!-- ----------------------------------- -->

  </div>


  <div class="col-md-3"> 

  <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
    <form>    
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>SubCategory</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="subcategories" ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-disabled="!selectedCategory"
         ng-options="categories.subCatName for categories in categories | filter: {catName:selectedCategory}" ng-change="getValue()">
             <option value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>
      </div>          
    </form>     
    <!-- ----------------------------------- -->

  </div>
```

This is my js code

```
    var appshop = angular.module('appShop', [ 'ui.router', 'angular.filter' ]);

    appshop.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/category');

        $stateProvider.state('addproducts',
        {
            url : '/addproducts',
            views :
            {                               
                'body' :
                {
                    templateUrl : 'category/manageproduct.htm',
                    controller : 'AddProductController'             
                }
            }
        })

        .state('addproducts.productsettings',
        {
            url : '/productsettings',
            views :
            {                               
                'productsbody@addproducts' :
                {
                    templateUrl : 'category/productsettings.htm',
                    controller : 'ProductsSettingsController'               
                }
            }
        })

    });

    //==========================================================

    appshop.controller('AddProductController',AddProductController);

    function AddProductController($scope, $http,$state)
    {
        $scope.onCategoryChange = function(category) 
        {
            if (!category) 
            {
                $scope.selectedSubCategory = undefined;

            }
        }   
        var categoryPromise = $http.get("../rest/mcategory");
        categoryPromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
        {
            $scope.categories=data;         
        });

        categoryPromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
        {
            alert("Error");     
        });     

        $scope.getValue=function()
        {       
            $state.go('addproducts.productsettings');       
        }   

    }

    //==========================================================

    appshop.controller('ProductSettingsController',ProductSettingsController);

    function ProductSettingsController($scope,$http,$state)
    {
        alert("Clicked")//I need to get alert here

    }
```

That two select boxes are come under AddProductController

And products are comed under nested state of this AddProductController it is named as ProductSettingsController

When i select both category and subcategory it works fine

But after selcting both then only to changed subcategory it wont works

Any idea for getting product details when i select subcatname? I need to get alert Clicked in ProductSettingsController
when i changed in subcategory selectbox

Comment: Are you getting selected subcategory?? If not try ng-Change="getValue(selectedSubCategory)"   then do   $scope.getValue= function(category) 
        {
           
            
                $scope.selectedSubCategory = category;

            
        }

Comment: Yea Got it Maheshji ,both Category and Subcategory is getting but problem is Initially we selct both it works fine but after when i chnage my subcategory content it wont reload that inner state.

Comment: @Maheshji got it my issue.

Comment: When i change my subcategory it hit alert in getValue() in AddProductController but $state.go('addproducts.productsettings'); is not working Why?

Comment: Simply try this .state('addproducts.productsettings', {
         
            url: '/productsettings',
           templateUrl : 'category/productsettings.htm',
                    controller : 'ProductsSettingsController'
        })

Comment: Comment the old code and try..

Comment: No Ji, I am screwed haha Actullay I tried but not working .The problem is this productssettings.htm is a nested state of addproducts.htm.Inside that addproducts.htm I added <div ui-view="productsbody"></div>